# Javascript doesn't work in Infinite Scroll

Tags: javascript, scroll, infinite

i applied [this](http://www.phpcluster.com/infinite-scroll-in-php-using-jquery-ajax-and-mysql.html) instructions to make an infinite scroll page. However, javascript codes didn't work on get_moredata.php

What should i do to active the javascript codes?

Comment: How can we help without having a look on your implementation.

Comment: There are 1483 lines in my get_moredata. I mean I have a lot of things in while loop. I can't copy here. But I did the same instructions as on the link.